# Java based Rate limiter with Redis + RollingLimit + backoff

Tags: javascript, java, redis, porting, rate-limiting

I am looking for a Java based ratelimiter approach similar to the javascript version [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-token-bucket-ratelimiter). I am essentially looking for a similar setup where I use the rolling-limit strategy tied to the timestamps and I get a back-off value in case the bucket is full.

```
const IORedis = require('ioredis')
const RollingLimit = require('redis-token-bucket-ratelimiter');
.
.
.
.

const limiter = new RollingLimit({interval:  reqInterval, limit: reqLimit,redis: redisClient, prefix: reqNamespace});

try {
    limit = await limiter.use(reqKey, reqAmount);
    /*
       Where limit is of format
        type RollingLimiterResult = {
  limit: number,      // the limit passed into `RollingLimiterOptions` on this invocation
  remaining: number,  // the number of tokens left in the bucket. Can be negative with `force`
  rejected: boolean,  // `true` if the request was rejected, `false` otherwise
  retryDelta: number, // if rejected, milliseconds to wait before making the next request
  forced: boolean,    // if `true`, `force` was on (see `RollingLimiterOptions`)
};
    */
} catch (e) {
    console.error(getMessage(e, reqNamespace, reqKey, reqAmount, reqInterval, reqLimit));
}
```

So far I looked at various approaches below but they do not return the backoff time that I am particularly looking for.

- [token-bucket-rate-limiter-using-spring-boot-and-redis-bucket4j](https://preethamumarani.medium.com/token-bucket-rate-limiter-using-spring-boot-and-redis-bucket4j-dd67e8c4f2ce) - this uses buckets but no timestamps or backoff logics
- I see the [reddision](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/6.-distributed-objects#612-ratelimiter) version related to this, which is good but still has a lot of other aspects that I cannot comprehend.
- I have approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977008/java-redis-rate-limiting) [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184965/redis-rate-limiter-pattern)  as pseudo code but unable to translate to Java

PS: any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance for you inputs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when saying that Bucket4j does not return backoff? In this example https://bucket4j.com/8.1.1/toc.html#limiting-the-rate-of-access-to-rest-api is described how to set up X-Rate-Limit-Retry-After-Seconds for HTTP response. Also library provides rich API https://bucket4j.com/8.1.1/toc.html#verbose-api that allows to get more diagnostic information.